# Nlog Date layout need to get the datetime offset with the long date

Tags: c#, nlog

Tried

```
${longdate:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm:ss.ffffK}
```

but its not writing in offset into the file using Nlog.
Tried

```
${date:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm:ss.ffffK}
```

it gives the offset and the time output.
Even tried `zzz` instead of `K`.

Can we give any other usage for getting the UTC offset in Nlog consoleLayout.Text?

Comment: What do you _get_ as a result and what do you _want_ as a result instead?

Comment: Soner,consoleLayout.Text = "${longdate}|${date:format= K}| worked fine.

Comment: i needed the date format to be ${date:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm:ss.ffffK}  but while using this was getting only the seconds,milliseconds and the offset portion. so insterted a pipe '|' between  date and offset and kept the date and offset as 2 different fields. consoleLayout.Text = "${longdate}|${date:format= K}|" .Thanks for responding.it would great help  if i could get the offset and date together without the pipe '|'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To log `DateTimeOffset` in database, I use this:

```
<parameter name="@logged" layout="${longdate}${date:format= K}" />
```

Please note, that space following `=` **really matters**! I checked NLog internal log and here is what I found:

Logged value (with space): `2017-04-21 10:05:48.1868000 +02:00`

Logged value (without space): `2017-04-21 10:05:48.1868000`

Hope it helped.

Comment: You need to use `%K`, see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-k-custom-format-specifier)

Answer (score 2):

```
${date:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.ffff}${date:format=%K}
```

will get you what you want

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I ran in to the same problem. The pipe solution didn't work for me. I ended up removing the date parameter from my NLog db target and letting the value get set by the db column's default setting which I had set to sysdatetimeoffset() when I originally defined the table.